# How to execute a program with only explicitly allowed set of system calls using seccomp?

Tags: linux, security

Linux have [seccomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) feature which be used to filter syscalls according to a [special program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter).

There is even [dropper.c](https://github.com/jrfastab/tx-rate-limits/blob/master/samples/seccomp/dropper.c) demo that allows to start programs with one syscall returning the given error.

Is there already implemented by somebody  any non-demo, more usable seccomp wrapper that allow me to execute a program with a whitelist of syscalls? Expecting something like this:

```
# limit_syscalls  access brk close connect dup \
      execve exit_group fcntl64 fstat64 getsockname \
      getuid32 mmap2 mprotect munmap open read set_thread_area \
      setuid32 socket write -- /bin/ping 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implemented myself](https://github.com/vi/syscall_limiter) using [libseccomp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libseccomp/).